# InvalidOperationalException base.Dispose(disposing)

Tags: c#, exception, dispose

I creating diagnostic application for PLCs. I have one form and a few Controls, which was inherited of UserControl. This Controls I switch. One view is Dashboard, Graph, and so on. When the graph is running, exception is occured. Exception is showed on line "base.Dispose(disposing)" in Form1.Designer.cs. Do you have any idea, how I can fix it? Thanks for any ideas.

---

This is code of Form1.Designer.cs. Error is show on line base.Dispose(disposing). Basicaly I don't know what this part of code do. That I can't repair it. Can somebody tell me, how it works? When is this part called? I don't find any use of method Dispose() in my program, only override methodes in each Control (inherited from UserControl). Thanks

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        /*Updated 8.4.2013*/
        //try
        //{
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        //}
        //catch { }
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.statusStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this.btn_ChangeLanguage = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.Zobraz_Palubka = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Zobraz_Verzi = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Zobraz_error = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Zobraz_Nastaveni = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Zobraz_TestIO = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Zobraz_monitor = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.statusStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // statusStrip1
        // 
        this.statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1});
        resources.ApplyResources(this.statusStrip1, "statusStrip1");
        this.statusStrip1.Name = "statusStrip1";
        // 
        // toolStripStatusLabel1
        // 
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Name = "toolStripStatusLabel1";
        resources.ApplyResources(this.toolStripStatusLabel1, "toolStripStatusLabel1");
        // 
        // btn_ChangeLanguage
        // 
        this.btn_ChangeLanguage.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.flag_cze_mini;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.btn_ChangeLanguage, "btn_ChangeLanguage");
        this.btn_ChangeLanguage.Name = "btn_ChangeLanguage";
        this.btn_ChangeLanguage.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btn_ChangeLanguage.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_ChangeLanguage_Click);
        this.btn_ChangeLanguage.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseEnter);
        this.btn_ChangeLanguage.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.trojuhelnik;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.pictureBox1, "pictureBox1");
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // Zobraz_Palubka
        // 
        this.Zobraz_Palubka.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.tachometr_mini;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.Zobraz_Palubka, "Zobraz_Palubka");
        this.Zobraz_Palubka.Name = "Zobraz_Palubka";
        this.Zobraz_Palubka.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.Zobraz_Palubka.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Click);
        this.Zobraz_Palubka.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseEnter);
        this.Zobraz_Palubka.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // Zobraz_Verzi
        // 
        this.Zobraz_Verzi.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.info_mini;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.Zobraz_Verzi, "Zobraz_Verzi");
        this.Zobraz_Verzi.Name = "Zobraz_Verzi";
        this.Zobraz_Verzi.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.Zobraz_Verzi.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Click);
        this.Zobraz_Verzi.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseEnter);
        this.Zobraz_Verzi.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // Zobraz_error
        // 
        this.Zobraz_error.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.error1_mini;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.Zobraz_error, "Zobraz_error");
        this.Zobraz_error.Name = "Zobraz_error";
        this.Zobraz_error.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.Zobraz_error.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Click);
        this.Zobraz_error.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseEnter);
        this.Zobraz_error.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // Zobraz_Nastaveni
        // 
        this.Zobraz_Nastaveni.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.settings_mini;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni, "Zobraz_Nastaveni");
        this.Zobraz_Nastaveni.Name = "Zobraz_Nastaveni";
        this.Zobraz_Nastaveni.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.Zobraz_Nastaveni.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Click);
        this.Zobraz_Nastaveni.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseEnter);
        this.Zobraz_Nastaveni.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // Zobraz_TestIO
        // 
        this.Zobraz_TestIO.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.testIO_mini;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.Zobraz_TestIO, "Zobraz_TestIO");
        this.Zobraz_TestIO.Name = "Zobraz_TestIO";
        this.Zobraz_TestIO.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.Zobraz_TestIO.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Click);
        this.Zobraz_TestIO.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseEnter);
        this.Zobraz_TestIO.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // Zobraz_monitor
        // 
        this.Zobraz_monitor.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.line_graph_icon_mini;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.Zobraz_monitor, "Zobraz_monitor");
        this.Zobraz_monitor.Name = "Zobraz_monitor";
        this.Zobraz_monitor.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.Zobraz_monitor.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Click);
        this.Zobraz_monitor.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseEnter);
        this.Zobraz_monitor.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(this.btn_ChangeLanguage);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Zobraz_Palubka);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Zobraz_Verzi);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Zobraz_error);
        this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Zobraz_Nastaveni);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Zobraz_TestIO);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Zobraz_monitor);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.statusStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.statusStrip1.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Zobraz_monitor;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Zobraz_Nastaveni;
    private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip statusStrip1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Zobraz_TestIO;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Zobraz_error;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Zobraz_Verzi;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Zobraz_Palubka;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btn_ChangeLanguage;
}
```

}

---

Here is exception detail:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateMenuHandles(MainMenu menu, Boolean forceRedraw)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateMenuHandles()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.MenuChanged(Int32 change, Menu menu)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in c:__*Projects*__\C#\RailJay Diagnostic SW\20130408\Motor\Motor\Form1.Designer.cs:line 23
       at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.DisposeThreadWindows()
  InnerException:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific - perhaps adding some code to what you are trying to do, where?

[EDIT]

As Jim mentioned, you are referencing a form from a seperate thread;

> Here is exception detail:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed
>   from a thread other than the thread it was created on

This means that you are trying to dispose Form1 from a thread that it was not created on.

Have you got sperate threads running in the application, if so, this is the first place to look.

Are you closing the Form1 anywhere within code?

Comment: I just realize, that i use threading for change language. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en"); I try to comment it and will see. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're calling `Dispose` from a thread other than the GUI thread. You can't do that.

Comment: but if I look for in whole project, that I can't find any instance or calling of Dispose method. So that is very incomprehensible for me...